# jQuery Cycle Plugin pager adding extra numbers, but no slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

Built a theme in HTML/CSS and customized a the cycle plugin to be a gallery with pagination. Worked perfect, now turning the theme into wordpress, and the pager is adding extra numbers, like blank slide between each image. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the 'slideExpr' option to specify which elements should be used as slides.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/slideExpr.html

Comment: Dude you are teh man! I have to use visual editor for this guys site so he does not see HTML, but WP kept adding p tags this time so nothing would rotate. So you just fixed my next problem I was working on. 
Is there anything you didn't think of with this thing? :) 
ps- can't wait for jQuery conference! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, odd. Was wordpress issue where it was adding in break ( `<br />`) tags automatically. 
Not helpful lol. If it happens to you, try adding this to the top of your template file,

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop'); ?>
```